# How to customize the hard wrap vertical line in Android Studio IDE for code formatting

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

When I apply "Format code" my lines of code automatically down line (many lines) even though my screen has enough space to display it on 1 line.

[image]

I see it depends on the vertical line (red in the image),
how can I remove this line or widen it?

My language is: Dart

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can disable the line from **File->Settings->Editor->Appearance** and then uncheck '**Show hard wrap and visual guides**'.

You can take reference from these two images:

'Show hard wrap and visual guides' **checked**
[image: With line]

'Show hard wrap and visual guides' **unchecked**
[image: Without line]

Also you can customize it from the 'Code Style' option in the same(Editor) dropdown.

For your reference:
Hard wrap with value 50:
[image: Hard wrap 50]

Hard wrap with value 100:
[image: Hard wrap 100]

**Edit:** for flutter development you need to the change the line length for auto formatting in dart option in the code style dropdown. Like this:
[image: Dart formatting]

*A lot of customizations could be done according to the need.*

Comment: @AnhTuan please check the edited part of the answer, might help further as you are developing using flutter

Comment: following setting worked for me:
preferences->Editor->Code Style->Dart->Line length