# Is there any way to disable hard wrap for specific file in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have hard wrap 100 and this is fine for me, but for some files I'd prefer do disable it. Is there any way? Like annotation or some config file...

Comment: Yes, there is. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71963228/

Comment: @Cornelis I don't see any option for SPECIFIC FILE, only for whole project

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question.

I don't think that is possible. You can set custom wrapping settings in Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> EditorConfig, but you can't filter on filenames